# Makefile C++11 - Compiling to static library

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, makefile

I am trying to compile my source files to a static library, however, it doesn't seem to want to work. Here is the code:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Usage of make file
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Clean operation:
#   make -f MakeClient clean
#
# Make operation:
#   make -f MakeClient
#
#


#OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
OBJ_DIR = ./obj

OUT_DIR= ../lib
OUT_FILE_NAME = libclient.a

# include directories
INCLUDES=-I. -I../common -I../../depends -I../../depends/zlib

# C++ compiler flags (-g -O2 -Wall)
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std+c++0x

  # compiler
  CCC = g++ 


  # Enumerating of every *.cpp as *.o and using that as dependency
  $(OUT_FILE_NAME): $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
    $(CCC)  -o $(OUT_DIR)/$@ $^ -static $(LIB_DIR) $(LIBS) -std=c++11

#Compiling every *.cpp to *.o
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp dircreation
$(CCC) -c $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

dircreation:
@mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)
@mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

.PHONY : clean
clean:
rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(OUT_DIR)/$(OUT_FILE_NAME) Makefile.bak
```

The problem seems to be recognising that I'm using C++11 since the actual code does not compile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `CCFLAGS` with `CXXFLAGS`, or vice versa.

And the flag is spelled `-std=c++0x` (thanks, @Pixelchemist).

Comment: SB If I use: `CCFLAGS` instead of `CXXFLAGS` I get the following: `g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-std+c++0x'`?

Comment: `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`. **=** not **+**.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Thanks.. That worked! But now I get the following error: `g++   -o ../lib/libclient.a obj/file1.o obj/file2.o -static   
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o`